# Plot stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe representing a table with 2 columns and 4 rows

```
Name | Value
 n1  | 10.3
 n2  | 5
 n3  | 15
 n4  | 8
```

I need to draw stacked bar (matplotlib) of values and the names should be shown in legend
I tried this (with no success):

```
df.count().unstack('Total_Sales')
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

How can I do it? I saw this question [Pandas - Plotting a stacked Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart). Not sure how to use it in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the names as categories you need to have them in the columns. So first set the index to `'Name'` and then transpose.

```
df.set_index('Name').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked plot]

Comment: Why should I transpose?

Comment: to get the names in columns instead of rows