# How to make a stacked graph directly from a python groupby code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make a chart after applying groupby

So I have applied

```
Sales_comparison = SalesData[['Region', 'Sales2015', 
'Sales2016']].groupby(['Region']).agg(['sum'])
```

I have tried for the graph

```
ax = Sales_comparison[['Sales2015','Sales2016']].plot(kind='bar', title 
="Sales by region comparison", figsize=(7.5, 5), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Region", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Sales", fontsize=12)
x = Sales_comparison.Region.index.tolist()
x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]
plt.xticks(x_pos, x)
plt.show()
```

But it is of no use

Is there any easier and shorter way to do what I want to achieve?

[image]

The data can be found in
[Link for the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxg7xDKnM8rncWx-z2P7xLc6N1wx9beN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) should work for you. [This answer should help you further along.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: So there is no need for indexation. If yes, then how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what you mean by indexation?
I assume you mean labeling in the graph, which would work in a similar way that you have already done.

```
Sales_comparison = df[['Region', 'Sales2015', 'Sales2016']].groupby(['Region']).agg(['sum'])

ax = Sales_comparison.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, legend=False,color=['navy','darkred'])
for i, label in enumerate(list(Sales_comparison.index)):
    S16 = int(Sales_comparison.loc[label]['Sales2016'][0])
    ax.annotate(str(S16),(i-0.2,S16+0.2*S16),color='white')
    S15 = int(Sales_comparison.loc[label]['Sales2015'][0])
    ax.annotate(str(S15),(i-0.2,S15-0.5*S15),color='white')
```

and result in the following image:
[End Result with Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Dzz.png)