# Plotly stacked bar chart pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe with a varying number of columns. With positive and negative values. Is it possible to make a stacked bar chart with all of these columns in the dataframe?

[image]

```
    A    B     C
0   34   34    -12
1   34   223   -12
2  34    56    -12
3   34   86    -12
4   56   86    -12
5   56   43    -12
6   78   34    -12
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(Updated answer for newer versions of plotly)*

Using [`px.bar`](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) will give you a stacked bar chart directly. If your bar chart for some reason is *not* stacked, try:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 34, 1: 34, 2: 34, 3: 34, 4: 56, 5: 56, 6: 78},
                     'B': {0: 34, 1: 223, 2: 56, 3: 86, 4: 86, 5: 43, 6: 34},
                     'C': {0: -12, 1: -12, 2: -12, 3: -12, 4: -12, 5: -12, 6: -12}})

colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.bar(df, 
             x = df.index,
             y = [c for c in df.columns],
             template = 'plotly_dark',
             color_discrete_sequence = colors,
             title = 'Stacked bar chart using px.bar()', 
             )

fig.show()
```

---

Old answer:

---

Here's a stacked bar chart using plotly offline in a Jupyter Notebook. Just make sure you have the packages listed under `imports` installed. `df = cf.datagen.lines()` produces a pandas dataframe with sample data from cufflinks.

**Plotly stacked bar chart:**

[image]

**Reproducible snippet:**

```
# imports
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# qtconsole for debugging
#%qtconsole --style vim #src# https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()
df = df[['UUN.XY', 'MJF.XV', 'XBB.AO']].head(50)
df=np.abs(df)

# make figure
fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='bar', barmode = 'stack',
               xTitle='Dates',yTitle='Returns',title='Returns')

# plot figure
iplot(fig)
```

---

**Edit -** Test with negative values

---

Here's the same thing run without the line  `df=np.abs(df)`

[image]

Comment: ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 3, whereas the length of previous arguments ['x'] is 7

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to make stacked bar plot directly with pandas by [using plotly as plotting backend](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/).

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'
fig = df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score -2):

Pandas DataFrame's [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) can also be used here.

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart) is a similar thread.

Comment: this isn't a plotly chart. Its need to be plotly