# Reshape dataframe and plot stacked bar graph

Tags: python, pandas

**What I have**

I have a frame `df` of the following style, where each row represents a malfunction occured with specimen:

```
index  specimen   malfunction  
1      'first'    'cracked'
2      'first'    'cracked'
3      'first'    'bent'
4      'second'   'bent'
5      'second'   'bent'
6      'second'   'bent'
7      'second'   'cracked'
8      'third'    'cracked'
9      'third'    'broken'
```

In real dataset I have about 15 different specimens and about 10 types of different malfunctions.

**What I need**

I want to plot a bar graph which represents how many malfunctions occured with specimen (so x-axis for specimen label, y-axis for number of malfunctions occured. I need a stacked bar chart so malfunctions must be separated by color.

**What I tried**

I tried to use seaborn's `catplot(kind='count')` which would be exactly what I need if only it could plot a stacked chart. Unfortunately it can't, and I can't figure out how to reshape my data to plot it using `pandas.plot.bar(stacked=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import pandas as pd

df = df.groupby(['specimen', 'malfunction']).count().unstack()
```

This generates the following table:

[Generated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3re9d.jpg)

```
fig, ax = subplots()
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)
ax.legend(["bent", "broken", "cracked"]);
```

The result is this graph:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URWMt.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I found this answer a little bit later here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart
So my question is kind of a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st step is to convert your categorial data in numeric:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df_toPlot = df #another dataframe keep original data in df

    df_toPlot['mapMal'] = df_toPlot.malfunction.astype("category").cat.codes
```

This is the print of df_toPlot.

```
             index specimen malfunction  mapMal
    0      1    first     cracked       2
    1      2    first     cracked       2
    2      3    first        bent       0
    3      4   second        bent       0
    4      5   second        bent       0
    5      6   second        bent       0
    6      7   second     cracked       2
    7      8    third     cracked       2
    8      9    third      broken       1


    df_toPlot.groupby(['specimen', 'mapMal']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
    plt.show()
```

[image]