# Bar plot and coloured categorical variable

Tags: python, plot, colors, bar-chart, categorical-data

I have a dataframe with 3 variables:

```
data= [["2019/oct",10,"Approved"],["2019/oct",20,"Approved"],["2019/oct",30,"Approved"],["2019/oct",40,"Approved"],["2019/nov",20,"Under evaluation"],["2019/dec",30,"Aproved"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Period', 'Observations', 'Result'])
```

I want a barplot grouped by the Period column, showing all the values ​​contained in the Observations column and colored with the Result column. 
How can I do this?

I tried the sns.barplot, but it joined the values in Observations column in just one bar(mean of the values).

```
sns.barplot(x='Period',y='Observations',hue='Result',data=df,ci=None)
```

[Plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTHA3.png)

Comment: Are you looking for a stacked bar chart with the observations summed? For an example, please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want one bar for each row, you can do as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

result_cat = df["Result"].astype("category")
result_codes = result_cat.cat.codes.values
cmap = plt.cm.Dark2(range(df["Result"].unique().shape[0]))

patches = []
for code in result_cat.cat.codes.unique():
    cat = result_cat.cat.categories[code]
    patches.append(mpatches.Patch(color=cmap[code], label=cat))

df.plot.bar(x='Period', 
            y='Observations',
            color=cmap[result_codes], 
            legend=False)
plt.ylabel("Observations")
plt.legend(handles=patches)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like it grouped by the months, and then stacked, please use the following (note I updated your code to make sure one month had more than one status), but not sure I completely understood your question correctly:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data= [["2019/oct",10,"Approved"],["2019/oct",20,"Approved"],["2019/oct",30,"Approved"],["2019/oct",40,"Under evaluation"],["2019/nov",20,"Under evaluation"],["2019/dec",30,"Aproved"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Period', 'Observations', 'Result'])


df.groupby(['Period', 'Result'])['Observations'].sum().unstack('Result').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks Tim, it is almost what I wanted, but Osbark got it.