# Stacked bar graph from multiple columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a stacked bar graph. This is my dataframe:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub3Kx.png)

I want the male and female columns stacked by year. How do I go about doing it.

I've tried

```
plotdata = yearly_data.DataFrame({"male", "female"},index = "year")
plotdata.plot(kind="bar")
data = data.set_index('year')
data[["male", "female"]].plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

I've even tried filtering by just one year to see if I can at least do an unstacked bar graph:

```
year = 2018
year_2018 = data.loc[year] 
plot_2018 = year_2018.plot(kind = "bar")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you include the example data as text? You could use for example `data.head()`.

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart) may help.