# How can I plot a stacked bar chart of median of a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

So I am a newbie learning about data visualization in pandas (python) , My task is to Create a stacked chart of median WeekHrs and CodeRevHrs for the age group 30 to 35.

following is my code where I extracted the data applying filter on age column and below are the first five rows of my dataset

```
age_filter= agework [(agework["age"]>= 30 )&(agework["age"]<=35)] 
median_weekhrs= age_filter["Weekhrs"].median()
median_coderev= age_filter["CodeRevHrs"].median()

age_filter.head()
```

```
    CodeRevHrs  Weekhrs age
5   3.0          8.0    31.0
11  2.0         40.0    34.0
12  2.0         40.0    32.0
18  15.0        42.0    34.0
22  2.0         40.0    33.0
```

How can I plot a stacked bar chart with a median?

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart

Comment: I need to plot the median, not sure how to do that since median is a single value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to filter for age (and also convert age to `int` as it makes for cleaner labels):

```py
df = agework.query('30 <= age <= 35')
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(int)
```

Then, you could plot a bar chart of the median of the two quantities in each age group:

```py
df.groupby('age').median().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.title('Median hours, by age')
```

[image]

BTW, you can impose an arbitrary order in how the values are stacked. For example, if you'd rather have `'Weekhrs'` at the bottom, you can say:

```py
order = ['Weekhrs', 'CodeRevHrs']
df.groupby('age')[order].median().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.title('Median hours, by age')
```

[image]

Now, if you'd rather plot the **overall** median of these quantities for the entire filtered age range (as you say: a single number for each quantity), then one way (among many) would be:

```py
label = f"{df['age'].min()}-{df['age'].max()}"
df.median().drop('age').to_frame(label).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.title(f'Median hours for age {label}')
```

[image]