# Frequency DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame containing a Datetime object each row with year, month, day and hour of the measurement. I have produced a basic bar plot for the frequency of each day. But I want to visualize on which hour the data was measured too. Is there a sort of plot who could be used for such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stacked bar chart where the day will be the x-axis, the hour will be a stacked column and the frequency of each will be on Y-axis.
Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart) to do that in pandas

Comment: Oh, didn´t thought of somethink like that. Nice idea, thanks!