# Plotting subdivided bar graph from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, bar-chart, graph-visualization

I have a Dataframe as given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'Dates': ['2021-04-11', '2021-06-08', '2021-06-08', '2021-06-09', '2021-06-10', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-18'], 
    'Results': ['Negative', 'Invalid', 'Negative','Negative','Negative', 'Negative', 'Positive' ], 
    'Size': [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 21, 2]
    
})
```

I want to plot a subdivided bar graph as shown below in the given picture.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have been stuck on this for a while now. Tried using groupby(), sum(), size() etc, but could not figure it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrKRY.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Plotting a stacked Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415500/pandas-plotting-a-stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: @ifly6 It doesn't. There the data is separated into columns wheres in my case, the data is present in a single column and it's categorical as well. Although it doesn't solve my question, I will try to get the idea out of this.

Comment: index on results then unstack. poof, you have your data separated into columns. it's even in the answer there: `df.groupby(['Name', 'Abuse/NFF'])['Name'].count().unstack('Abuse/NFF')`

Comment: @ifly6 In my Dataframe, I need the 'size' column which gives the number of count each result occurred on that day.  So, I cannot be using the  count() function as given above

Comment: yea so don't write the _exact_ same code, adapt the code there, set indices and unstack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reshape it by setting indices on date and results, then unstacking `Results`. After that, plot.

```
df.set_index(['Dates', 'Results']).sort_index(0).unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

If you don't want it with a column multi-index, and instead want "Invalid", "Negative", "Positive", just create an intermediate data frame from the `unstack` (I'll call it `temp`) and assign `temp.columns = temp.columns.get_level_values(1)`. Then call `temp.plot.bar(stacked=True)`.

---

To specify size using the OOP `matplotlib` interface:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(HEIGHT, WIDTH))
temp.plot.bar(ax=ax, stacked=True)
```

Save the figure to file using `f.savefig(PATH)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I understand it now. One more thing, is there a way to increase the size of the chart displayed? The graph displayed has many dates and its cramped in the default size. Thank you.

Comment: See edit. tl;dr is to set figure size with `figsize`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am very new to graphs and hence these silly questions. Thank you